# How to get the number of people in a GetSatisfaction community for Shields.io?

Tags: get-satisfaction, shields.io

Using the GetSatisfaction API, how can I get the number of community members? I want to use this number to great a GitHub shield using Shields.io.

API: https://education.getsatisfaction.com/reference-guide/api/api-resources/

There are a number of endpoints and it looks like the following People endpoint should do what I want:

```
GET /companies/{community_id}/people.json
```

But when I call this, I don't get the right figure.

For example, the homepage of the RingCentral Community says 10,035 members but the following API only returns 933 people, where `102909` is the `community_id` as shown in View Source of the community page.

- API URL: http://api.getsatisfaction.com/companies/102909/people.json
- Web page URL: https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com

Source excerpt:

```
GSFN.Authenticatable.companyId = 102909;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured this out. To get this number, call the Company API directly and look for the `approximate_people_count` figure:

```
GET /companies/{community_id}.json
```

- API URL: http://api.getsatisfaction.com/companies/102909.json

This will return a JSON object with the following property:

```
"approximate_people_count":10042
```

Once you have this, you can use the Shields.io `uri`, `query`, and `suffix` parameters as follows:

- `uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.getsatisfaction.com%2Fcompanies%2F102909.json`
- `query=$.approximate_people_count`
- `suffix=%20members` (optional, shown below)

Put this together for:

[image]

https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json.svg?label=community&colorB=&suffix=%20members&query=$.approximate_people_count&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.getsatisfaction.com%2Fcompanies%2F102909.json

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using [Badgen](https://badgen.net), here is the Badgen way to do that:

1. Create a RunKit endpoint (using it's handy online editor) do the works, query json & get count result, then response a json: `{subject: '', status: '', color: ''}`, like https://runkit.com/amio/peoples
2. Use `https://badgen.net/runkit/:endpoint_id/:args` to serve badge from that endpoint. Here's the badge url: https://badgen.net/runkit/peoples-txwpy888xiuk/102909

[image]

With Badgen you can have a cleaner url, and create badge from more complicated api source, thanks to RunKit endpoint.

Here's a full featured example: https://runkit.com/amio/satisfaction

- ```
  https://badgen.net/runkit/satisfaction-flq08o9mm3ka/102909/employee
  ```
- ```
  https://badgen.net/runkit/satisfaction-flq08o9mm3ka/102909/people
  ```
- ```
  https://badgen.net/runkit/satisfaction-flq08o9mm3ka/102909/topic
  ```

[image]   [image]   [image]